# calling javascript function from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to call a javascript function from code behind on the button click event. below is my javascript code.

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "strScript", "javascript:clearBox();", true);
```

and the function is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function clearBox() {


    alert("Test");

}
</script>
```

I get an error "Object expected"

Comment: I see no button in your code.

Comment: ..and what seems to be the problem? or your *question*?

Comment: It looks like you are using inline JS. If so please don't and use an eventListener.

Comment: You get the error "Object expected" _where_ exactly?  What code is actually throwing the error?  It sounds like a JavaScript error, so the C# code won't be the place to look.  Whatever is emitted to the client is where you'd look.

Answer (score 4):

You should use OnClientClick property of a button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="clearBox()" />
```

`RegisterClientScriptBlock` will only place a piece of code on a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      javascript:clearBox();
</script>
```

And this will not work as it is not a valid code (because of `javascript:` which is used for anchors to run js from href: `<a href="javascript:some_code_here()"></a>`)

Another option, if you want `RegisterClientScriptBlock` is to use addEventListener to assign onclick handler to your button. [Here](http://snipplr.com/view/561/) is code snippet for this (cross browser and pure JS). It may be used like this:

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "strScript", "addListener('"+button.ClientID+"', 'click', clearBox);", true);
```

But it is better to replace `RegisterClientScriptBlock` with `[RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx)`
where first one may be called before all HTML is loaded and there may be no button yet.

**Upd**
Well, thanks to [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd). He reminded me that there are [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) in JS and actually `javascript:clearBox()` is a valid code, but it will not do what OP wants

Comment: "as it is not a valid code" -- it's an unused useless label attached to a statement, but I believe it's perfectly valid. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) for how labels work in JS, they're not often used (and for good reasons), but they are part of the language.

Comment: Hm.. need to try. But I do not think so) Let me check that with js fiddle

Comment: @hvd Uh. Sorry. I see your point. Never use that thing and actually forgot about that possibility

Comment: Perhaps worse: it will do exactly what the OP wants, but for the wrong reasons. The label will just be ignored if it is unused, so `clearBox` will be called as intended.

Comment: @hvd yeah, you are right. But he wants to call it on click, so "will not do what OP wants" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),  "Error", "clearBox();", true);
```